# document.getElementById.innerHTML = variable not changing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="Num"></p>
  <p id="musicTitle"></p>
  <button onclick="next()">pipi</button>
  <audio controls>
  <source id="songSrc" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

  <script>
    Num = 1
    const maxNum = 2
    document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num

    song = [{
        title: "evil forest",
        src: "https://files.catbox.moe/c5zrzm.mp3"
      },
      {
        title: "forest",
        src: "https://files.catbox.moe/c5zrzm.mp3"
      },
    ]

    let music = document.getElementById("music");
    music.src = song[Num - 1].src;
    document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title;

    function next() {
      if (maxNum > Num) {
        Num++
      } else {
        let Num = 1
      }
      let music = document.getElementById("music")
      music.src = song[songNum - 1].src
      document.getElementById("musicTitle").innerHTML = song[Num - 1].title;
      document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

1. I wanted Num to change as you click the button, but it either doesn't change the variable or doesn't reflect the change in document.getElementById.
2. song title isn't showing even though I made song title variable and made document.getElementById statement.

Comment: `document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = Num` changes the DOM **once**. It does not create a permanent relationship to the variable `Num`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("music")` - You have no element with that ID.

Comment: `song[songNum-1].src` - You have no variable called `songNum`.

Comment: Overall, this is probably a good time for you to start using your browser's development tools.  You can observe error messages on the console, as well as use the script debugger to step through the code as it executes and observe its exact behaviors and results.  There are a variety of oversights made in this code, and a debugger is exactly the tool a developer users to find and correct those oversights.  When you do this, is there a specific problem you struggle to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

In the next() function you are redeclaring Num with let. This creates a new local variable instead of updating the global one. Instead, you should remove the let keyword inside the else block to update the global variable.

```
if (maxNum > Num) {
                Num++;
            } else {
                Num = 1; //this way you update the global num and you don't create a new one
            }
```

Second, You're using songNum instead of Num when accessing the song array. I I think it should be Num

`music.src = song[songNum-1].src` 
should be
 `music.src = song[Num-1].src`

Hope it helps

Comment: 1. I learned about difference about local and global variable thanks to you, didn't get what using 'let' meant before. though, it doesn't change the problem that id="Num" doesn't change when I click the button. 2. do you have any idea what to do about the id="musicTitle" not showing?